# Why do we pass in a function as an argument without execution in django?

Tags: python, django

When creating a post model that includes title, content, and author, I wrote `author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` for the author because one author can have many posts. My question is why is the function passed to the `on_delete` parameter not executed. In other words, why isn't it `on_delete=models.CASCADE()` instead(note the parentheses)?

Comment: Because the `ForeignKey` expects the function, not the result of calling the function. This particular examples is sometimes termed a "callback". More generally speaking, Python supports first-class functions and higher order functions, that is, functions are just like any other value, functions are objects and can be used wherever any other object can be used (assigned to a variable, put in a data structure, like a list or a dict, or passed as a parameter or returned from another function). A higher order function is just a function that takes a function as a parameter or returns a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because then you will *immediately* evaluate the function when the interpreter sees `models.CASCADE`.

The idea is that we pass a *function* to the `on_delete` parameter, not the result of calling that function, such that *later*, when the `User` is deleted, the Django framework will *call* that function to collect the objects that refer to that user, and delete these as well.

This thus means that we do not per se will call the function when you run the server, or that we can call it multiple times. Furthermore the trigger functions [require arguments](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/deletion.py#L15-L19):

> ```
> def CASCADE(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
>     collector.collect(sub_objs, source=field.remote_field.model,
>                       source_attr=field.name, nullable=field.null)
>     if field.null and not connections[using].features.can_defer_constraint_checks:
>         collector.add_field_update(field, None, sub_objs)
> ```

The `collector` here collects extra objects that should be removed (and recursively keeps doing that).

Answer (score 1):

`models.CASCADE` is just a callback used by Django to simulate database constraints. Indeed from [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py)

```py
if not callable(on_delete):
    raise TypeError('on_delete must be callable.')
```

It is saved as a ForeignKey class attribute when the model is defined and when a delete occurs this function is executed.